# Why is the Secondary Name Node included on the slaves file as well?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am reading blogs and tutorials and noticed that the node that is configured on the masters file is also included in the name node, why are they including the secondary name node on the slaves file as well? A technical or conceptual explanation is very much appreciated

Comment: Clarify more about your question.

Comment: Question updated,, the main question is why is the node on the master file of hadoop also included on the slaves file

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure both master processes and slave processes on the same node in a cluster. But it is not recommended in production. In production, you will not see the overlap between masters and slaves. However on single node Hadoop set up as well as small clusters for development, it is common to have overlap between master and slave processes.

- Master processes: namenode, secondary namenode, resource manager, jobhistory server etc.
- Slave processes: datanode, nodemanager etc.

If you have node as part of masters and based up on the ip address in core-site.xml and yarn-site.xml it will start namenode and resourcemanager respectively.

For slaves configuration files typically have 0.0.0.0 as ip address, so it will start both datanode as well as nodemanager on all the nodes that are defined as slaves (unless you exclude it).